# Writing to the stream buffer of a string stream overrides the previous data

Tags: c++, stream, stringstream, ostream, streambuf

What I want to do is to  create   string stream , and output stream, giving the buffer of string stream to output stream, so that  it will output data  to the string stream. Everything seems fine, but  when I try to add  data to buffer of the string stream it overrides the previous data. My question is why? and how can achieve  a result, such that it does not override but simply adds to the string stream. Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

 int main ()
{

 stringstream s1("hello I am string stream");
 streambuf *s1_bfr =  s1.rdbuf();
 ostream my_stream (s1_bfr);
 my_stream <<"hey"<<endl;
 cout <<s1.rdbuf()<<endl; //gives the result  : " hey o I am string stream"( seems to me overriden)


return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you using the stringstream like that? Why `rdbuf` ? Why not simply `<<` into the stirngstream?

Comment: Because I wanted to do it with buffer, and I don't  understand why it's not working.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: heyhello I am string stream

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append the data in the beginning:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
        stringstream s1("hello I am string stream");
        streambuf *s1_bfr =  s1.rdbuf();
        stringstream temp; //Create a temp stringsteam
        temp << "hey"; //add desired string into the stream
        temp << s1_bfr; //then add your orignal stream
        s1 = move(temp); // or ss.swap(temp); 
        cout <<s1_bfr<<endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```